# Application-wide style with GTKMM4

Tags: gtkmm4

I've got some custom styles for widgets that I've put together in a css file. I've loaded this with code like this:

```cpp
  auto provider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
  provider->load_from_path("./res/themes/custom/gtk.css");
```

And then set the style individually for widgets by getting their context and adding the provider with code like this:

```cpp
  auto ctx = widget->get_style_context();
  ctx->add_provider(provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to just set this for the entire application. Is there a way to set a css/style provider application wide?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Just use Gtk::StyleProvider::add_provider_for_display() as noted here: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtkmm-documentation/sec-custom-css-names.html

---

Yes, there is such a way. Unfortunately, I'm currently only working with C and not with gtkmm.
However, the difference should not be that big. That's why I recommend the following
Q&A. Transferring to Gtkmm will certainly not be a problem.

[GTK4 widget customizations using CSS providers do not consistently work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71365107/22768315)

[CSS Styles not applied in GTK4 C language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77379769/22768315)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try adapting this soon.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to replicate this. There is no equivalent method to gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display in GTKMM4 (*there was in GTKMM3?) and extracting the GObj for the Provider and Display and passing them to gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display doesn't seem to have any effect. I think GTKMM is somehow handling or abstracting the Display in some way that prevents the provider from actually being added or preventing the provider from being applied to all the components in the already initialized application.

Comment: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtkmm-documentation/sec-custom-css-names.html   Could this help?

Comment: I think it will! Specifically: ```Then add it with Gtk::StyleProvider::add_provider_for_display() (available since gtkmm 4.10)```. 4.10 just happens to be the latest packaged version so I'll try it out tonite.

Comment: It worked! Can you write an answer saying something like: "Just use Gtk::StyleProvider::add_provider_for_display() as noted here: https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtkmm-documentation/sec-custom-css-names.html" so I can accept it? I'd like to give you full credit for the accepted answer.